# Framework7 grid layout to include desktop view

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-framework-7

I know that framework7 is designed for phones and tablet but is there a way to include or somehow tweak the css to make it compatible for desktop?my scenario is i have two div elements that i want to view side by side on desktop.

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-50">panel-1</div>
      <div class="col-50">panel-2</div>
    </div>
```

But on tablet/phone view i want it to view both as 100%

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="tablet-100">panel-1</div>
      <div class="tablet-100">panel-2</div>
    </div>
```

I tried below but the documentation said tablet class is for window width >= 768px, so the width is 100% even on desktop view.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-50 tablet-100">panel-1</div>
      <div class="col-50 tablet-100">panel-2</div>
    </div>
```

I am thinking of adding a custom css like desktop-XX, but how can i add it and overwrite the current grid system? Any suggestion would be great thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (min-width:768px){
.col-50{
width:50%;
}
}
```

this should work

Comment: The col-50 is already declared on framework7 so i changed it to desktop-50 but still it doesn't display 50% on desktop.

Comment: add it with minimum media (768)